# How to find the local maxima and minima in an image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, mask, javacv

I am learning how to get the local and global maximum in an image, and as far as know, in one image there is only one global Maximum and one global minimum, and i managed to get these values and their corresponding locations in the image. so my questions are:

1. how to get the local maxima in an image
2. how to get the local minima in an image
3. as you see in the code below, I am using mask, but at run time i receieve the below mentioned error message. so please let me know why do we need mask and how to use it properly.

**update**:

Line 32 is: `MinMaxLocResult s = Core.minMaxLoc(gsMat, mask);`

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MatFactory matFactory = new MatFactory();
    FilePathUtils.addInputPath(path_Obj);
    Mat bgrMat = matFactory.newMat(FilePathUtils.getInputFileFullPathList().get(0));

    Mat gsMat = SysUtils.rgbToGrayScaleMat(bgrMat);
    Log.D(TAG, "main", "gsMat.dump(): \n" + gsMat.dump());

    Mat mask = new Mat(new Size(3,3), CvType.CV_8U);//which type i should set for the mask

    MinMaxLocResult s = Core.minMaxLoc(gsMat, mask);
    Log.D(TAG, "main", "s.maxVal: " + s.maxVal);//to get the global maximum
    Log.D(TAG, "main", "s.minVal: " + s.minVal);//to get the global minimum
    Log.D(TAG, "main", "s.maxLoc: " + s.maxLoc);//to get the coordinates of the global maximum
    Log.D(TAG, "main", "s.minLoc: " + s.minLoc);//to get the coordinates of the global minimum
}
```

**error message**:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (A.size == arrays[i0]->size) in cv::NAryMatIterator::init, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 3197
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:3197: error: (-215) A.size == arrays[i0]->size in function cv::NAryMatIterator::init
]
at org.opencv.core.Core.n_minMaxLocManual(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Core.minMaxLoc(Core.java:7919)
at com.example.globallocalmaxima_00.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:32)
```

Comment: Which one is line 32?

Comment: @ScottHunter please see the update section above

Comment: Local != Image.Local maxima and minima are applied to the region covered by your mask not the whole image.

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate global min/max values you don't need to use `mask` completely.

For calculating local min/max values you can do a little trick. You need to perform dilate/erode operation and then compare pixel value with values of original image. If value of original image and dilated/eroded image are equal therefore this pixel is local min/max.

The code is following:

```
Mat eroded = new Mat();
Mat dilated = new Mat();
Imgproc.erode(gsMat, eroded, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(5,5)));
Imgproc.dilate(gsMat, dilate, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(5,5)));

Mat localMin = new Mat(gsMat.size(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(0));
Mat localMax = new Mat(gsMat.size(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(0));

for (int i=0; i<gsMat.height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<gsMat.width; j++)
    {
         if (gsMat.get(i,j) == eroded.get(i,j))
             localMin.put(i,j,255);
         if (gsMat.get(i,j) == dilated.get(i,j))
             localMax.put(i,j,255);
    }
```

Please note, I'm not a Java programmer. So, code is only illustration of algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i have a question please, why did you use the type CvType.CV_8U? why if i used CvType.CV_32f?

Comment: @user2121, It doesn't matter what type to use. But in case CV_32f you may need to compare float values by norm of difference, as follows: `abs(gsMat.get(i,j) - eroded.get(i,j)) < epsilon`

Comment: Nice, but if you need to find all local minima/maxima use a 3x3 rect as a structuring element